# How to make the button change with the size of the text in it

Tags: javascript, css

As you see in my example on the following link, if the number increases then the text will overflow from the button. How can I make it flexible to always fit with the size of button?

[The Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/ps8L9pve/15/)

```js
$("button").html('<span>Production:</span></br></br><span class="blue" >555555555</span>');
```

```css
.Btns {
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 6vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn" type="button" class="Btns"></button>
<button id="btn1" type="button" class="Btns"></button>
<button id="btn2" type="button" class="Btns"></button>
<button id="btn3" type="button" class="Btns"></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just remove the `width:100px;` then the button size will automatically change to the size of its content.

```js
$("button").html('<span>Production:</span></br></br><span class="blue" >555555555</span>');
```

```css
.Btns {
               
            height:75px;
            background-color:lightblue;
            color:black;
            font-weight:bold;

        }

      .blue {
       color:blue;
       font-size:6vw;
       overflow:hidden;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" type="button" class="Btns" >
 
      </button>
      <button id="btn1" type="button" class="Btns" >
 
       </button>
      <button id="btn2" type="button" class="Btns" >
 
      </button>
      <button id="btn3" type="button" class="Btns" >
 
       </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width:100px;` and replace it with `width:auto;`. And you should probably also raise the heigth a little bit, so that the text fits in the button

```js
$("button").html('<span>Production:</span></br></br><span class="blue" >555555555</span>');
```

```css
.Btns {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 6vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn" type="button" class="Btns"></button>
<button id="btn1" type="button" class="Btns"></button>
<button id="btn2" type="button" class="Btns"></button>
<button id="btn3" type="button" class="Btns"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a fixed width use padding:

```
.Btns {
  padding: 6px;
}
```